# Cannot run firefox, chrome, terminal on VNC

Tags: internet, gnome-terminal, vnc, cloud

I am having a problem related to my virtual machine at Google cloud. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my virtual machine instance. I am using vnc to connect to it. But after setting up everything as specified by tutorials, the gui is not as it is in ubuntu 16.
[VNC gui for ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX44Z.png)

Moreover, I am unable to open gnome-terminal on it. After accessing virtual machine through my computer I have installed chrome, but when I click on it a tab opens for "Starting chrome" and then it close. 
Here is my configuration of xstartup file.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop"           &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

Please help me, how should figure out the problem.